# Pass array of objects to component not working

Tags: angular

I am wondering why this is working:

```
<div *ngFor="let image of recipesList | slice:0:10">
   <div>{{image.recipe_id.food_name}}</div> <!-- Outputs a list of food names -->
</div>
```

And why I am not able to pass this `recipesList` (array of objects) data into a component

```
<app-planning [recipeData]="recipesList"></app-planning>
```

Planning component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-planning',
  templateUrl: './planning.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./planning.component.css']
})
export class PlanningComponent implements OnInit {

   @Input() recipeData: [];

   constructor() {
   }

   ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(this.recipeData); // Returns an empty array
   }

}
```

Comment: recipeList or recipesList?

Comment: @Giannis recipesList, excuse me.

Comment: No worries. So, app-planning is the child component, but what is the value of recipesList  in the parent component?

Comment: @Giannis an array of objects representing days including recipes. So I want to show these days in a week planning. And that is where the planning component is created for. Is that clear enough for you?

Comment: It seems you get the `recipesList` via API? If so it's empty when the component is initiated.

Comment: `ngOnInit` is called *way* before the HTML-template is being rendered and its content runs. You will most likely want to use `ngOnChanges` in order to check if the input value changed and react on it.

Comment: @yash yes that is true. It is a meal plan module with an API call for all the data with among others data for the days including recipes.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner okay thanks for the help. I am going to try to implement it on ngOnChanges. But do you maybe think I have to restructure this another way instead of passing the data to the planning object?

Comment: The only thing I suggest to change would be the type. The input is *always* possibly undefined, give that the parent is responsible to pass a value into the child which "takes time".

Comment: @PhilippMeissner ngOnChanges works and shows me the data. With changing the type of input you mean from array to ... ?

Comment: @Robbert `@Input() recipeData?: [];`

Comment: @PhilippMeissner okay great thanks! You made my day ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because @Input change detection works only with immutable objects. There are many [articles](https://vsavkin.com/immutability-vs-encapsulation-90549ab74487) about it.

In short if you push into input array - it will not work, but if you update reference to an array - it will work.

```
<app-planning [recipeData]="recipesList"></app-planning>

// Component
recipesList.push(newItem) // View will not be updated

recipesList = [...recipesList, newItem]; // View will be updated
```

Comment: I don't see how the reference to the structure would in any way produce the error OP describes. It's a lifecycle issue, not a reference issue.

Comment: Robbert said that recipeData returns empty array but not undefined. So it means array is already constructed, and according to provided solution it is constructed in a parent component